# Exporting weather data as CSV or XLS file

Tags: export, excel, csv-format

I am relatively new to mathematica, and sorry if this question is too simple.
I am trying to export weatherdata to a csv or xls file.

```
data = WeatherData["Chicago", "Temperature"]    
Export["C:\\***filepath****\\weather.csv", data, "csv"]
```

When I open the file with excel, in the A1 cell I get "Quantity[26.1" and in the B1 cell I get  ""DegreesCelsius"]"
I want just the 26.1.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

```
data = WeatherData["Chicago", "Temperature"];
degrees = QuantityMagnitude[data]
Export["C:\\***filepath****\\weather.csv", degrees, "csv"]
```